# Authentication error connecting to MS SQL DB on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, t-sql

My current setup is a Windows MS SQL server set up with Active Directory. I have an account on the Active Directory. I need to use Windows authentication to log in. I'm trying to connect to the SQL server via tsql from a Linux box. To do this, I'm running the following:

```
tsql -S <server> -U <active_direct_domain\\username>
```

This is failing with the error code:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18452 (severity 14, state 1) from SYMPLECTIC03 Line 1:
    "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I've also tried running it without the domain:

```
tsql -S <server> -U <username>
```

And get the following error:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from SYMPLECTIC03 Line 1:
    "Login failed for user 'username'."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I have no idea what is going wrong here. Apparently, I don't have the ability to connect via tsql through Windows authentication, but shouldn't I if I am on the Active Directory? Does tsql not support Windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing. I would first start to see if you can connect with a sql account not an ad account.

Microsoft has an ODBC driver for sql server from linux. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx